# Scientific notation into binary notation

Tags: computer-science, scientific-notation

$0.25E3 = 0.25 \cdot  10^3 = 250$.  I am trying to write it in binary notation which should be something like for example if binary is $11111010$ then the binary would be in scientific notation $0.11111010 \cdot 2^7$. Here I am really confused how much I should place the dot in the left side. what is the actual expression. I understand it would be minus when point goes to right side and positive when goes to left side. But how many times it has to go and on what basis?

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste and context. If you're dealing with numbers in the order of a million, for example, it would be wise to write $2\cdot10^6$ instead of $2000\cdot 10^3$.

Comment: Yeah. But the task demanded the binary notation. That's why i am trying to understand this particular term.